# How to trigger onChange on an ObservableObject?

Tags: swift, swiftui

Let's suppose a simple `ObservableObject`view model with a few published properties.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: ViewModel, rhs: ViewModel) -> Bool {
        lhs.value == rhs.value &&
        lhs.anotherProperty1 == rhs.anotherProperty1 &&
        lhs.anotherProperty2 == rhs.anotherProperty2 &&
        lhs.anotherProperty3 == rhs.anotherProperty3
    }
    
    @Published var value = 0
    @Published var anotherProperty1 = "foo"
    @Published var anotherProperty2 = "bar"
    @Published var anotherProperty3 = "baz"
}
```

I would like `onChange` to be triggered *no matter which `ViewModel` property is modified*.

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            viewModel.value += 1
        } label: {
            Text("Increment value \(viewModel.value.formatted())")
        }
        .onChange(of: viewModel) { _ in debugPrint("viewModel did change") } // FIXME: does not trigger :(
    }
}
```

Here I change `value` for example. Why is `onChange` never triggered?

Comment: just use: `.onChange(of: viewModel.value){...}`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I want `onChange` to be triggered when any `ViewModel` property changes, not just `value`.

Comment: View will be redrawn anyway. Why you want to print "viewModel did change" every time?

Comment: This is the wrong approach, in SwiftUI the View struct has this change detection built in, just call `DemoView(value: value)` and `body` is called when value has changed. value can be anything even a struct that groups mutiple vars.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is onChange never triggered?

Because it's a class (reference type) and the reference of the class (unlike a **struct**) does not change on any modification of a property.

But maybe you don't understand the functionality if `@Published`.
You don't need `onChange` at all because `objectWillChange` will be called automatically whenever one of the `@Published` properties changes. That's the main goal of `ObservableObject`.

Answer (score 0):

One workaround is to create an additional variable that changes whenever any of the other ones changes.

For example, variable `status` in the example below will have a different value any time one of the other variables changes. Then, you monitor the changes only for the variable `status`.

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject, Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: ViewModel, rhs: ViewModel) -> Bool {
        lhs.value == rhs.value &&
        lhs.anotherProperty1 == rhs.anotherProperty1 &&
        lhs.anotherProperty2 == rhs.anotherProperty2 &&
        lhs.anotherProperty3 == rhs.anotherProperty3
    }
    
    @Published private(set) var status = UUID()
    
    @Published var value = 0 { didSet { status = UUID() } }
    @Published var anotherProperty1 = "foo" { didSet { status = UUID() } }
    @Published var anotherProperty2 = "bar" { didSet { status = UUID() } }
    @Published var anotherProperty3 = "baz" { didSet { status = UUID() } }
}
```

In the view:

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            viewModel.value += 1
        } label: {
            Text("Increment value \(viewModel.value.formatted())")
        }
        .onChange(of: viewModel.status) { _ in debugPrint("viewModel did change") }
    }
}
```

Comment: if you don't want to create new UUID objects all the time I suppose it would be enough to let `status` be a boolean and do `status.toggle()` in all `didSet`. It should be enough since the requirement isn't a unique value but only that the value changes.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson: I thought about a boolean, but in some extreme cases (2 or more variables changing simultaneously) I was afraid the boolean would rapidly go back to the value before the changes. But yes, in most cases a boolean is more than enough.

Comment: Looks like you are correct, I update the second property in the didSet of the third one and the updates happens in the same SwiftUI life cycle so they cancel each other out. An extreme or at least unrealistic example but still.

Answer (score 0):

All `ObservableObject`'s have `objectWillChange` publisher. You just need to observe it.

For example you can do it with `Concurrency`:

```
struct DemoView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            debugPrint("viewModel will increment")
            viewModel.value += 1
            debugPrint("viewModel did increment")
        } label: {
            Text("Increment value \(viewModel.value.formatted())")
        }.task {
            for await _ in viewModel.objectWillChange.values {
                debugPrint("viewModel did change")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For some reason, that I haven't figured out yet, this solution will lead to a crash _if_ the observable object also uses Combine publishers itself (it's the other publisher and not this solution that crashes). I have reproduced in two different classes while a third class without any other publishers worked fine.

Comment: I couldn't let this go and made some more isolated tests, if you use the view code in the question and add a TextField for any of the other 3 published properties then this solution will lead to a crash withe the error `Received an output without requesting demand`. This is the same as in my previous comment but now the second publisher is the other `@Published` property that can be modified. Sorry but this is not a working solution unless for the (rare?) case that you have only one publisher active.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson, all is fine with `VStack {Text(viewModel.anotherProperty1)Text(viewModel.anotherProperty2)Text(viewModel.anotherProperty3)Button {`. May be there is problem in how you use that publishers?

Comment: No, you misread my comment. Use `TextField` and not `Text` so that the properties can be modified (so that you actually access the publisher using $).

Comment: @JoakimDanielson something wrong with `.values`. If implement `AsyncStream` it works fine.